# Powershell - mySQL Query, error every other run

Tags: mysql, powershell

I am working on a powershell script that needs some input from a mySQL database. For the life of me I can't tell what I've done wrong here.

Every other time I run this script, I get an error `Exception calling "Open" with "0" argument(s): "Out of sync with server"[0]`. So, the first run, it will pull the expected data and dump it on my screen, then on the next run I get that error. And the cycle just repeats. Here is my full code (right now its just a test query to pull then dump the data. If it matters, the mySQL server is running MariaDB 10.3.14 on a Ubuntu 18.04 host.

```
$error.Clear()

$sqlQuery = get-content -path "C:\querytext.sql" -Raw
$sqlUser = "myuser"
$sqlPass = "mypass"
$sqlHost = "myserver"
$sqlDB = "dbname"
$connectionString = "server= $sqlHost;port=3306;uid=$sqlUser;pwd=$sqlPass;database=$sqlDB"

Try{
    $connection = New-Object MySql.data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection
    $connection.ConnectionString = $connectionString
    $connection.Open()
    $command = New-Object MySql.data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand($sqlQuery,$connection)
    $dataAdapter = New-Object MySql.data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataAdapter($command)
    $dataSet = New-Object System.Data.DataSet
    $dataAdapter.fill($dataSet, "data") | Out-Null
    $command.Dispose()
    $sqlResults = $dataSet.tables["data"]
}
Catch {
    Write-Host "ERROR : Unable to run query : $query `n$Error[0]"
}

$connection.close()

$sqlResults | Format-Table

$sqlResults | ForEach-Object {
    write-host $_.fname
}
```

Comment: Of note, if I wait a while, it seems to run with no issues.

Comment: Not an answer but you can use `$_.Exception.Message` instead of `$Error[0]`. The `[0]` in ur error message was misleading.

Comment: @RohinSidharth that does remove the final `[0]` from the error, so now I have `Exception calling "Open" with "0" argument(s): "Out of sync with server"` as the error.

Answer (score 0):

Might I suggest using the SQL PS module:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/powershell/download-sql-server-ps-module?view=sql-server-2017

That page has installation instructions and its from Microsoft. Personally, the dotnet class you are using, it works, but its relatively difficult to work with.

Connecting to a DB is much simpler with this module and you do not have to worry about micromanaging connections.

```
Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $sqlHost -Query $sqlQuery -Database $sqlDB -Username $sqlUser -Password $sqlPass
```

This will return a PS object like every other PS cmdlet.